# It's possibile to use set function on a object basing only one attribute?

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7

I'm creating this type of object:

```
class start_url_mod ():
    link = ""
    id = 0
    data = ""
```

I'm creating a list of this object and I want to know if there is some way in order to delete one of then if I find same link attribute.
I know the function `set()` for the deleting of duplicates in a "sample" list, but there is something very fast and computational acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `dict` key-ed on the attribute. You can preserve order with [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Keep the last copy with a given link
kept_last = OrderedDict((x.link, x) for x in nonuniquelist).values()

# Keep the first copy with a given link (still preserving input order)
kept_first = list(reversed(OrderedDict((x.link, x) for x in reversed(nonuniquelist)).viewvalues()))
```

If order is not important, plain `dict` via [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#dictionaries) is significantly faster in Python 2.7 (because `OrderedDict` is implemented in Python, not C, and because dict comprehensions are optimized more than constructor calls; in Python 3.5 it's implemented in C):

```
# Keep the last copy with a given link but order not preserved in result
kept_last = {x.link: x for x in nonuniquelist}.values()

# Keep the first copy with a given link but order not preserved in result
kept_first = {x.link: x for x in reversed(nonuniquelist)}.values()
```

Comment: Oh, just noticed: In both cases for preserving order, a non-unique entry will be _ordered_ based on the _first_ time the `link` was seen, but have the _value_ associated with the _last_ time the `link` was seen. Avoiding this would mean converting the one-liner to an explicit loop that checks for and `del`s the `link` before reinserting so the order matches the value. Of course, if order doesn't matter, so you're not using `OrderedDict` anyway, then you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary with the attribute that you're interested in being the key ...